# Почему у овец бывает окот?

Tags: этимология

Корова телится, кобыла жеребится, собака щенится, кошка котится. Но почему роды у овец тоже называют окот? При чем тут коты?)))

Comment: Если бы овцы находили ягнят в капусте, тогда бы у овец не было окота.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Интернете на эту тему есть  ответ по ссылке  http://otvet.mail.ru/question/6552471

Основные мысли:

"В отношении животных уместно говорить, что «щенятся» не только суки, но и другие самки того же семейства: волчицы, лисы или близкие к ним по виду барсучихи и росомахи, ибо нет необходимости изобретать нелепые глаголы вроде «барсучиться» или «росомашиться».

Но овцы, конечно, могут только «ягниться»: такое слово существует в русском языке сотни лет, и нет никакой необходимости заменять «ягнение» — «окотом»".

Мне могут возразить, что об «окоте» овец упоминает сам Даль, правда с оговоркой: «верней, объягнение».

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Возможно, слова "ягнение, объягниться" всё-таки не кажутся благозвучными,да и в записи выглядят не очень симпатично. Не для каждого животного можно подобрать удачный термин.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Кажется, в первый раз не хочется поверить Фасмеру и Шанскому по поводу "окотиться".
Кот - общеславянское слово, в древнерусском языке с 11 века. Общеславянский вариант заимствован из латинского, но и в неиндоевропейских языках оно широко известно, латинский вариант восходит к нубийскому (родиной кошки считается Африка).
"Котиться" от "катать" Шанский называет общеславянским вариантом. А вот происхождение у общеславянского "катать" (kotiti/katati) не самое благородное, то есть неясное (возможно исходным корнем является sket с потерянyым в дальнейшем s).

Фасмер считает, что влияние слова кошка на "окотиться" вторично, что и кажется сомнительным. Когда произошло это вторичное влияние, если кошка - это давно одомашненное животное? Значение "окотиться" понятно, если речь идет о появлении котят, тогда можно объяснить значение морфем О, СЯ, иначе было бы "выкотиться". Да и рождение других животных (например, отелиться, ощениться) когда так стали называть? Поэтому вопросов больше, чем ответов.

Answer (score 5):

*Котиться* имеет 2 значения.

Малый академический словарь

Кот*и*ться, несов. (сов. окот*и*ться).

1. Рождать котят (о кошке).
2. Рождать детенышей (о некоторых самках, например об овце, козе, зайчихе).

При этом такие разные животные не столько рожают **котят**, сколько **выкидывают** потомство из чрева.

Этимологический словарь (http://etymological.academic.ru/2251/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F):

*Котиться*

Общеслав. Возвратн. форма к котити («метать, кидать»), того же корня, что катать, качать. Буквально — «метать, выкидывать» (из чрева). Ср. метать икру, выкидыш.

Так что *окот* по исходному значению практически универсальное слово для процесса рождения потомства.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю компромисс!

Если в "кошаре", то "котятся"... Соответственно, в "овчарне" непременно "ягнятся"!

Типа двойные стандарты - не только у нас... 
Велик могучим руски языка!

Comment: Даже в слове СКОТ буква С выглядит как пра-приставка.
Плюс прилагательное СУКОТНАЯ.